# Python and ReportLab: add a string at the end of every page

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm building a pdf document with reportlab, using the Paragraph class:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, leftMargin=lateral_margin, rightMargin=lateral_margin,
    topMargin=top_bottom_margin, bottomMargin=top_bottom_margin)
Document = []
Document.append(Paragraph("bla bla bla bla", my_style))
doc.build(Document)
```

Now I want to add at the end of every page a string, how can I do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `build` call can include `onFirstPage` and `onLaterPages` arguments, which are functions invoked when the page starts.  You can draw on the canvas in those functions to create fixed-position elements on each page, like page headers and footers.